# How to get refences to the instances involved in stack trace of Java exception?

Tags: java, swing, exception

When given an Exception object in Java, is there any way to get (or infer) the instances involved in the stack trace of this exception? I know that `StackTraceElement` contains information about the *classes* involved, but what about the actual instances?

In case you're wondering, I'd like to use this in a `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` that displays error dialogs. The plan is to figure out which `JFrame` produced the unhandled exception and set that as the parent (this would affect positioning of the dialog, modality (which window it blocks) etc).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no standard API that supports that. My advise is as follows:

If you have a thread per JFrame just add a field to the Thread such that it will know what JFrame is associated with it such that it can manipulate it when an exception is caught.

Otherwise, if you have a central thread that carries out jobs dispatched by several JFrame objects, add a JFrame field to the job object such. When cataching an exception extract the JFrame from the Job object and you're good to go.

Comment: Is it possible to have a seperate thread for each JFrame ? AFAIK all GUI code in a Swing application is run through the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: A GUI app can launch one (or more) Threads. These new threads should not do GUI-related operations. When they do need to do so they can use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). I thought that in your scenario is about these "secondary" threads. If not, could you clarify?

Comment: I'm not the poster of the question, had posted a comment to know more about the answer you had posted. Thanks.